# Check for data availability in Pandas Remote Data Access

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

Having a huge list of stocks and ETFs, I am trying to filter them by some criteria. The problem is that my program stops each time it finds a symbol for which data are not available. Is there is a way to check for data availability first and consider only those symbols for further analysis?

I am using the following command for data access:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Comment: Have you considered a try/except block?

Comment: Excellent! No it works:

Comment: try:
      x = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
    except IOError:
      print('cannot open', stock)

Comment: Great that you figured it out. Please post it as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered list.